# Landscape and header formatting

Tags: tables, graphics, header-footer, landscape

Hello I am really new at this.

I am trying to represent a .pdf with the following specifications:

-a4 papper
-orientation: landscape

-Special header with three divisions

-after header divide in 4 (2 graphs and 2 tables) (simetric)

More or less something like this.

[image]

Can anyone help me with the code of the structure of this??

I would be really gratefull

Comment: Close the other one this has an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried anything on your own? Without more info on what this is supposed to be and what you've already tried it is hard to really know what you're trying to achieve.

That said, have a look at the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{%
    text1 \hfill
    text2 \hfill
    text3 \hfill\hfill
    \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{left image}\label{img_left}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{right image}\label{img_right}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Images}\label{images}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c}
            Table & Col Header & Col Header\\
            \hline
            Row Header & cell 1 & cell 2\\
            Row Header & cell 3 & cell 4\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{left table}\label{left_right}
    \end{subtable}
    \begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c}
            Table & Col Header & Col Header\\
            \hline
            Row Header & cell 1 & cell 2\\
            Row Header & cell 3 & cell 4\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{right table}\label{tbl_right}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Tables}\label{tables}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image: output page]

For having multiple lines of text in any of parts of the header, use `\parbox` as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,landscape]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\usepackage{pbox}
\fancyhead{%
\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{text1\\and more}\hfill
\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{text2\\and more\\even more}\hfill
\parbox{0.2\textwidth}{text2}\hfill\hfill
    \includegraphics[height=2\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{left image}\label{img_left}
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfill
        \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
            \caption{right image}\label{img_right}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Images}\label{images}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c}
            Table & Col Header & Col Header\\
            \hline
            Row Header & cell 1 & cell 2\\
            Row Header & cell 3 & cell 4\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{left table}\label{left_right}
    \end{subtable}
    \begin{subtable}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c c}
            Table & Col Header & Col Header\\
            \hline
            Row Header & cell 1 & cell 2\\
            Row Header & cell 3 & cell 4\\
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{right table}\label{tbl_right}
    \end{subtable}
    \caption{Tables}\label{tables}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which makes the header look like:

[image: multi-line header]

Comment: is that posible to those text sections in header have multiple lines? I mean using '\\' before \hfill???? because if i try to do that apper in the 3 sections the same text..............

Comment: using a `\parbox{<width>}{text\\moretext}' instead of what was `text1` should work.